# Syntax Error For Exponential Growth Program

Tags: calculator, exponential, exponent, texas-instruments, ti-basic

I am working on a calculator program for a geometry midterm project. It involves making 5 programs for commonly used equations. One of my programs is exponential growth. The prompts in the beginning appear and work, but when I try to have the program solve the equation, a Syntax Error pops up.

I am using the TI-84 Plus calculator and the TI Connect CE software to do the programming.

My code:

```
Lbl 4
ClrHome
0→I
0→G
0→O
Input "ORIGINAL AMT.=",I
Input "GROWTHRATE(Dec.)=",G
Input "PERIOD OF TIME=",Q
Goto M
Lbl M
ClrHome
Output(I(1+G))^(Q)
Pause 
ClrHome
Menu("TRY AGAIN?","YES",4,"NO",6)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you run the code, and press `2) GOTO` when the program has failed, what line of code does it bring you to?  I think I know where the error may be, but I want a little more information before I make a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the mistakenly using the `Output(` command instead of `Disp`. Try replacing `Output(I(1+G))^(Q)` with `Disp I(1+G)^Q` like so:

```
Lbl 4
Input "ORIGINAL AMT.=",I
Input "GROWTHRATE(Dec.)=",G
Input "PERIOD OF TIME=",Q
ClrHome
Disp I(1+G)^Q
Pause 
ClrHome
Menu("TRY AGAIN?","YES",4,"NO",6
```